# Callback when adding new tweets on twitter

Tags: php, twitter

Is there a way to get notified on my server every time I add new tweet on twitter? I need to save each post I write on twitter into my database but this should be real time. e.i. I don't want to check for new tweets in a specified time intervals, but get a notification about new tweets as soon as they are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should use the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods). This'll allow you to connect to the API and listen for all new tweets from specific accounts.

Of course, this isn't a callback. Twitter doesn't provide those. Streams are as close as you're going to get using official features.